# Playing an mp3 tone on Android application - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio, playback

Im trying to play an mp3 tone in my PhoneGap application. Works fine with iOS but the tone wont play on Android (4.2.2).

html

```
 <audio type="audio/mp3" id="audiotag1"  
src="http://url.com/tone.mp3" preload="auto" >
 </audio>
```

js:

```
 document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot play mp3 files inside of a webview for Android using strictly html5. You have to use Cordova's Media object:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_media.md.html

Comment: So did this work for you? If it did it would be great if you could mark it as your answer. Otherwise most people will assume that it did not work for you.

Comment: Apologies, yes it worked great thanks. Have marked as answer.